# Having a list of objects , how to pass a single object to each mapper class using mapReduce?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Two questions about the WordCount example:
http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount

1. If I understand correctly in the example: 
   the main class receive an input file (line 57) 
   and each mapper receive a single line of that file (line 22)?
2. I am trying to do something a little different:
   instead of passing an input file to main class, 
   let's say my main class has a list of some object

for example:     List Transition transactionsList;

and I want each mapper to receive a single item in this list:

in my example:   Transition singleTrans ;

How can I do something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first question:

Yes, line 57 adds the first argument you're passing to the job as the job's input. It will then launch `N` mappers and each mapper will receive a **split** of the input file. Check [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HowManyMapsAndReduces) for more information on how many mappers will be launched. By default, Hadoop assumes that every line of the input contains a key/value pair (the input to a single map call).

Regarding your second question:

You can't pass Java objects as an input to your job as Hadoop can't read input from memory. To feed your list of objects as input, you would first need to write your objects to a file on disk either using some textual representation or using some serialization format (e.g. [Apache Avro](https://avro.apache.org/) or [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo)). You can then use this file as an input and deserialize it in your map function.

Alternatively, you can define your own [custom input format](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat) to deserialize your data while reading it and then feed the actual objects to your mappers.